# Tomcat can not forward error code 500 when the page too large

Tags: tomcat, error-code

My environment:
ubuntu 18.04
openjdk version "1.8.0_181"
tomcat 7.0.91

And I put these into WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/500.html</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/500.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Now I write a test.jsp as:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<c:forEach begin="1" end="1000" step="1" var="i">
just test exception forward.
</c:forEach>
<%
    Object o = null;
    String s = o.toString();
%>
</body>
</html>
```

It will get an exception and goto /500.html. but it can not, when the exception, it just include the 500.html into current page.

I think the page is too large, if I put end="100" of c:forEach, it will forward 500.html.

How to fix this please?

Comment: You need to understand that at some point the servlet container (Tomcat) decides to actually start sending data over the wire (usually when an output buffer reaches some threshold). If anything happens after that point, there is nothing much a server can do to take back the data that has already been sent. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#isCommitted()

Comment: @PavelHoral Thank you. and is there a parameter to adjust buffer-size please?

Comment: I am not sure as I never needed to change such thing.... maybe `socket.appWriteBufSize` https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html . But I would say you just need to write your app in a different way... maybe don't write Java code into JSP as that is considered a bad practice.

Comment: @PavelHoral Thank you. but it can not work. There are few java code in jsp (3 lines), just some el expression. but too many html(compressed) in it. Now I put the 3 lines java code to the head of jsp, it will ok.